# Capturar submit de un Iframe

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una página web que trae un Iframe que contiene un formulario con su botón submit, lo que busco es hacer un código *javascript* (no vale jquery) que cuando se pulse el botón que está dentro del Iframe poder realizar una función JS.

Del código me encargo yo, pero necesito saber como hace que mi javascript o mi página web,navegador... detecte que se ha pulsado ese botón que está dentro de un Iframe.

PD: Yo no creo el Iframe ni ese botón, sino le pondría un onclick o algo así, pero no.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener desde el padre un `iframe` utiliza:

```
parent.window.frames['IdIframe'].document.body
```

Con esto obtienes el `iframe` y puedes entrar a todas sus funciones, con:

```
parent.window.frames['IdIframe'].tuFuncion();
```

Puedes lanzar un evento desde el padre.

**Edición**

Te dejo también una función de ejemplo con lo que uso en mi proyecto para capturar múltiples `iframes` y ejecutar una función común.

Parte Parent:

```
 tutorial.click(function () {

        //obtener frame
        var obj = parent.window.document.body.children;

        var frames = [];


        for (var i = 7; i <= 28; i++) {

            frames.push(obj.item(i));           
        }


        $.each(frames, function (key, value) {

            var cuerpo = parent.window.frames[value.id].document.body;

            if (value.style.display == "block") {

                parent.window.frames[value.id].lanzar();
            }       
        });


    });
```

Parte Children:

```
function lanzar() {

        //Tu evento
    }
```